# Why look ahead at most 1 input token?

Tags: parsing, regex-lookarounds, ll-grammar

I'm currently trying to implement LL parser but I have a question.
Need I to look ahead at most 1 input token for verify if the user's input
is syntactically correct or it's for another reason?

Answer (score 2):

There are many different kinds of parsing algorithms. The one you're describing is called LL(1) and by definition it just uses one token of lookahead. However, there are other parsing algorithms that use more lookahead than this. For example, an LL(2) parser uses two tokens of lookahead, and an LL(*) parser has unbounded lookahead. There are grammars for which one token of lookahead isn't enough (that is, grammars that are LL(2) but not LL(1)). Here's an example:

> S → n | n + S

Try working out why one token of lookahead isn't enough, but two tokens suffices.

The reason parsing algorithms try to keep the number of lookahead tokens low is for simplicity and efficiency. As the number of lookahead tokens increases, the size of the parsing table needed to drive the parser increases, as does the complexity of building those tables.

Comment: @S7_0 I'm not sure there's a way to determine this without trial and error. Sorry!